# Windows key database for WDS

Tags: windows, wds, keys

I wonder if there is any solution to have windows key database and use it in Windows Deployment process. If you know some or how please share

Comment: Sorry but this makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to use individual retail or OEM licenses with WDS. Don't do this, get volume licenses so that you have KMS or a single Multiple Activation Key(MAK) available.

Comment: In my business we have tones of OEM and I would like to do WDS with some like database that we don;t need to write keys always be hands. KMS or MAK isn't decision what we need :)

Comment: Then you're going to have to probably write one yourself. WDS and most other imaging deployment software was designed for use with a MAK or with KMS. It might not be what you want to hear, but it's the truth. Why do you have so much OEM anyway? It starts to be cost efficient to get a volume license after about 5 computers in most cases.

Comment: This is long long story

Comment: You're probably going to have to roll your own solution and handle the creation and deletion of keys from the database yourself. Then just write a little program or script that's called from the unattend file and uses `slmrg.vbs -ipk` to input the correct product key once it's retrieved from the database. Alternatively, you can just not do anything with the key at all and have a manual input of the key handed by the technician doing the actual imaging. Unfortunately, you have to resort to dirty tricks when you start doing things outside of the expected way :(

Comment: We can ONLY buy OEMs then upgrade them to Windows 7 Enterprise - which is a pain because Microsoft don't allow upgrades from Windows 7 Pro - you have to do a fresh install.  Maybe it isn't the same everywhere, or with customers of different scales.  We have about 800 PCs and still have to buy Windows 7 Pro OEM from Dell :-(

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provide their own [Key Management Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff793434.aspx) for automatic product activation of Windows.  Is this what you are asking about?